# LInq to sql query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a sql query as follows:

```
  Declare @DivisionNo INT

  SET @DivisionNo = 5117



  SELECT distinct CASE WHEN ISNULL([DivisionNo],'') <> @DivisionNo 
                       THEN @DivisionNo ELSE [DivisionNo] END as DivisionNo

      --,[RecordID]    
      ,[AcctCat]    
      ,[AcctCatDesc]    
      ,[CostCode]    
      ,[CostCodeDesc]

  FROM [dbo].[vw_eSchdl_AcctCat_CostCode]    
  WHERE DivisionNo = @DivisionNo

  UNION

  SELECT distinct CASE WHEN ISNULL([DivisionNo],'') <> @DivisionNo 
                       THEN @DivisionNo ELSE [DivisionNo] END as DivisionNo

      --,[RecordID]    
      ,[AcctCat]    
      ,[AcctCatDesc]    
      ,[CostCode]    
      ,[CostCodeDesc]

  FROM [dbo].[vw_eSchdl_AcctCat_CostCode]    
  WHERE AcctCat not in (
      SELECT [AcctCat]     
      FROM [dbo].[vw_eSchdl_AcctCat_CostCode]
      WHERE DivisionNo = @DivisionNo
  )
```

How can I duplicate it using linq to sql?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you get part way, but get stuck somewhere? Can you post what you have? Which bit gives you problems? Or have you no clue where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no better way to learn than to do it yourself using [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) if you have a bit of time. You can have a tab with the SQL open and a tab with LINQ and try to duplicate your query results.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert from SQL to Linq using [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/). You can download it from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/progClean/Linqer-Clean-101979.html).

Comment: @Mark - LinqPad will not convert SQL to Linq. However, a product named Linqer will.

Answer (score 0):

How about functionally equivalent?

```
int divisionNo = 5117;

var matches = from ac in context.AcctCatCostCodes 
              where ac.DivisionNo == divisionNo
              select ac;

var missingAcctCat = from ac in matches
                     select ac.AcctCat;

var others = from ac in context.AcctCatCostCodes
             where !missingAcctCat.Contains(ac.AcctCat)
             select ac;

var union = from ac in matches.Union(others)
            select new
            {
                DivisionNo = ac.DivisionNo ?? divisionNo,
                ac.AcctCat,
                ac.AcctCatDesc,
                ac.CostCode,
                ac.CostCodeDesc
            };
```

... same as methods instead of query syntax ...

```
var matches = context.AcctCatCostCodes
                     .Where(ac => ac.DivisionNo == divisionNo);

var missingAcctCat = matches.Select(ac => ac.AcctCat);

var others = context.AcctCatCostCodes
                    .Where(ac => !missingAcctCat.Contains(ac.AcctCat));

var union = matches.Union(others).Select(ac =>
             new
            {
                DivisionNo = ac.DivisionNo ?? divisionNo,
                ac.AcctCat,
                ac.AcctCatDesc,
                ac.CostCode,
                ac.CostCodeDesc
            });
```

... SQL generated by LINQ2SQL ...

```
SELECT COALESCE([t4].[DivisionNo],@p2) AS [DivisionNo], 
       [t4].[AcctCat], 
       [t4].[AcctCatDesc], 
       [t4].[CostCode], 
       [t4].[CostCodeDesc]
FROM (
    SELECT [t3].[AcctCat], [t3].[AcctCatDesc], [t3].[CostCode], 
           [t3].[CostCodeDesc], [t3].[DivisionNo]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[RecordID], [t0].[AcctCat], [t0].[AcctCatDesc], 
               [t0].[CostCode], [t0].[CostCodeDesc], [t0].[DivisionNo]
        FROM [AcctCatCostCode] AS [t0]
        WHERE [t0].[DivisionNo] = @p0
        UNION
        SELECT [t1].[RecordID], [t1].[AcctCat], [t1].[AcctCatDesc], 
               [t1].[CostCode], [t1].[CostCodeDesc], [t1].[DivisionNo]
        FROM [AcctCatCostCode] AS [t1]
        WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [AcctCatCostCode] AS [t2]
            WHERE ([t2].[AcctCat] = [t1].[AcctCat]) 
                  AND ([t2].[DivisionNo] = (@p1))
            ))
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [t4]
```